# HTML5 Form Validation Without Submission

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

For a signup page, I'm trying to implement form validation (e.g. no empty fields) and email / password verification (e.g. email hasn't already been used) via Firebase.

Below is an image of what I want to occur when an email has been previously used to create an account.

[image: Expected Behavior]

However, the current issue is if the HTML5 client-side form validation goes through, it will submit without going through Firebase server-side email and password validation.

Ideally upon clicking sign-up, it will go through form validation => Firebase validation => form submission. But right now, the logic is form validation => submission =/> Firebase validaiton.

Is there a way to have the email / password be verified before the form is reset?

---

**EDIT 1**: I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mn2peL1/) for convenience.

An account with the email test@test.com has been made to show that pre-existing emails don't result in an error when submitting the form.

---

**EDIT 2**: Found a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/0mn2peL1/5/)! Add a hidden input with type submit.

```
    #validate {
        display: none;
    }

    <form id="signup-form">
        <div class="line input-group">
            <input type="submit" id="validate"/>
            <button id="signup" class="btn glow-button" type="button">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form> 

    var form = document.getElementById('signup-form');
    if (!form.checkValidity()) {
         form.querySelector('#validate').click();
    }
```

Comment: your code looking correct, but just the line  `window.onload = firebase.auth().signOut();` looking odd. **can you test by removing this line....!**

Comment: I removed the line and the problem of the form resetting after clicking "sign up" still persist, regardless of whether the email has already been used or if the password is not strong enough.

Comment: change your code as per below explanation...!

Answer (score 3):

This is demo for blocking submission of form till validation is not done...! use "tushar" as first name to submit successfully.

Return `True` if all field are well validated otherwise return `false` so your form will not submitted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form onsubmit="return toSubmit();">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="name" type="text" name="firstname" >
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" >
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form> 

<script>
   function toSubmit(){
     if(document.getElementById('name').value == "tushar"){
      alert("success");
      return true;
     }
     else{
        alert("failed");
        return false;
     }
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your jsfiddle, the problem is due the automatic form submission on the click of submit button. if your validation is failed then you should block submit-event.

I don't know exact reason of that submit-event, but to prevent automatic submit-event i have removed `class="btn glow-button"` from submit button.

As you are using firebase, all operation will done by asynchronously, you don't need to submit your page at server...!

*Insert below code, I hope it will work.*

```
    <form id="signup-form">

        <div class="line input-group"> 
            <input id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First name" class="focus" required>
            <input id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last name" class="focus" required>
        </div>

        <div class="line input-group"> 
            <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" class="focus" required>
        </div>

        <div class="line input-group">
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Create your password" class="focus" required>
        </div>

        <div class="alert" id="email-error">
            <p>An account has already been registered with this email. <a href="/sign-in.html">Log in</a> to your account.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="alert" id="passw-error">
            <p>Password is too weak. 6 characters or longer required.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- this code-block commented
        <div class="line input-group">
            <button id="signup" class="btn glow-button">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
        -->

        <!-- this is code-block is added-->
        <div class="line input-group">
            <button id="signup" class="">Sign Up</button>
        </div>          

    </form>
```

Comment: Yes, test@test.com is already an email that has been used. However, if all the fields are non-empty, and the sign-up button is clicked, the form is reseted without alerting the user that the email is invalid (as described in the picture).

Comment: Thanks for the update; a way to block the automatic submission I found was to add type="button" explicitly since by placing any button in a form, its default type is "submit". Change is reflected [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0mn2peL1/2/). However, I'm noticing the "please fill out this form" pop-up is gone now. While it is minor, is there a way to get that back?

Comment: cool...just change type from `button` to `submit` then "please fill out this form" popup will come....and don't forget to **upVote** &  **mark as Correct** my answer....! upVote will help other to solve their issues....!

Comment: However, that would then cause the form to automatically submit -- thus warnings would not pop up.

Comment: mention jsfiddle in question is not replicating your problem....! have you change it...?

Comment: Try having "test@test.com" as the email and some string greater than 6 characters as the password, and leave the first name and last name fields empty. The Sign Up button will proceed without form validation, which I want.

Comment: The basic logic I want is: form validation => email and password verification => form submission. However, I can't get form validation, and email and password verification to work at the same time.